# Significance of selection sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

What is the significance of selection sort? It has a time complexity of O(n^2) even in best case scenario. So why is it still prevalent?

Comment: It is typically used as a *benchmark* algorithm. Something to compare against. For example if you want to specify how many swaps Tim sort performs, you can compare that with the number of swaps of selection sort for the same unordered list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It is simple to write and intuitive for people to understand
- It is the closest to the way real humans approach sorting lists.
- It functions in-place in memory
- After n iterations you know the first n elements are sorted. After the first iteration the first item is sorted, after the second is finished the first 2 are sorted, etc...

Comment: plus: It makes at most n-1 swaps - sometimes this is useful for big data records with small key

Comment: plus: It uses fewer writes than insertion sort.